# Django TypeError: 'totask' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, arguments, keyword, typeerror

I have a model for users to add time to a task.

```
class Time(models.Model):
    to_task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    appuser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

However when I try to create an instance of this model by using the following:

```
t1=Time(totask=task, appuser=user, hours=6.75)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'totask' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.
```

I have not made any models with multiple ForeignKeys before so am thinking that it could be because of that. However I have seen examples in the Django documentation with two ForeignKey's and they did the exact same as I did.

After many searches I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have define it as `to_task` in your model so you need to use the same name when creating an instance:

```
t1 = Time(to_task=task, appuser=user, hours=6.75)
```

Don't forget to save it:

```
t1 = Time(to_task=task, appuser=user, hours=6.75)
t1.save()
```

You can use the `create` method too:

```
t1 = Time.objects.create(to_task=task, appuser=user, hours=6.75)
```

Comment: Wow, I must be literally retarded, it was a typo that whole time. thanks haha

Answer (score 3):

Umm... this seems impossibly wrong, but your field is `to_task` *not* `totask`. Use the actual field name and you're golden.